# Suppress slideshow caption if alt text is blank

Tags: jquery, slideshow, caption

I'm working with a simple jQuery slideshow that creates a caption over an image by using the text from the image's title and alt text. It works great, but I don't want it to display anything when an image in the slideshow doesn't have a title/alt.

See the example code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qWZWJ/24/

I basically need to add an IF statement to test if the image title/alt is blank, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the "display the caption" content on your javascript to this:

```
//Display the caption
if($('#slideshow-caption p').html() != "")
    $('#slideshow-caption').css({opacity: 0.7, bottom:0});
```

enjoy :)

Comment: I added the code, and now it doesn't display the caption for any of them, even if they have title/alt attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Hey srry this is a fix:

use this as your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {        

    //Execute the slideShow, set 4 seconds for each images
    slideShow(2000);

});

var timer;

function slideShow(speed) {


    //append a LI item to the UL list for displaying caption
    $('ul.slideshow').append('<li id="slideshow-caption" class="caption"><div class="slideshow-caption-container"><h3></h3><p></p></div></li>');

    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('ul.slideshow li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
    $('ul.slideshow li:first').css({opacity: 1.0}).addClass('show');

    //Get the caption of the first image from REL attribute and display it
    $('#slideshow-caption h3').html($('ul.slideshow li.show').find('img').attr('title'));
    $('#slideshow-caption p').html($('ul.slideshow li.show').find('img').attr('alt'));

    //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow    
    timer = setInterval('gallery()',speed);

    //pause the slideshow on mouse over
    $('ul.slideshow').hover(
        function () {
            clearInterval(timer);    
        },     
        function () {
            timer = setInterval('gallery()',speed);            
        }
    );

}

function gallery() {


    //if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
    var current = ($('ul.slideshow li.show')?  $('ul.slideshow li.show') : $('#ul.slideshow li:first'));

    //trying to avoid speed issue
    if(current.queue('fx').length == 0) {    

        //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
        var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().attr('id') == 'slideshow-caption')? clearInterval(timer) :current.next()) : $('ul.slideshow li:first'));

        if (next) {    

            //Get next image caption
            var title = next.find('img').attr('title');    
            var desc = next.find('img').attr('alt');    

            //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
            next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

            //Hide the caption first, and then set and display the caption
            $('#slideshow-caption').slideToggle(300, function () {
                $('#slideshow-caption h3').html(title);
                $('#slideshow-caption p').html(desc);
                if(desc != "" || title != "")
                {
                    $('#slideshow-caption').css({opacity: 0.7, bottom:0});   
                    $('#slideshow-caption').slideToggle(500);                                         
                }
            });        

            //Hide the current image
            current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000).removeClass('show');
        }
    }

}
</script>
```